# Relative vs. non-relative module import for custom modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

**Update[09/12/2017 16:58 EST]**

Added reason why I hesitate to use the natively-supported non-relative import with my own modules to the bottom of this question.

**Update[09/12/2017 12:58 EST]:**

Per request, I made the file structure below reflect my actual use case. Which is a nested view module requesting a utility module somewhere up the directory tree.

---

Per request

In both TypeScript and ES6, one can import custom module by

```
// Relative
import { numberUtil } from './number_util';
// OR
// Non-relative
import { numberUtil } from 'number_util';
```

And according to TypeScript docs ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)), one should:

> ... use
>   relative imports for your own modules that are guaranteed to maintain
>   their relative location at runtime.
>
> ... Use non-relative paths when importing any
>   of your external dependencies.

My problem here is that I have a project structure like this:

```
project/
  |--utils
  |    |--number_util.ts
  |--views
  |    |--article_page
  |         |-- editor_view
  |                |--editor_text_area.ts
```

And when I include `utils/number_util` inside my `editor_text_area` module, the import statement looks like:

```
import { numberUtil } from './../../../utils/number_util';
```

Which is long and not readable and, worst of all, difficult to maintain: whenever I need to move `editor_text_area`, I will have to update each these relative paths, when in the meantime I can just use the non-relative way of

```
import { numberUtil } from 'utils/number_util';
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to do module imports to achieve the highest readability and maintainability?

---

But using the non-relative way poses a problem (other than that it is not recommended by official docs): what if I installed an `npm` module that has the same name with the module I'm importing? On that note, it is not as **safe** as the uglier alternative mentioned above.

Comment: Usually a nested hierarchy that deep is a sign of an architecture issue. What's making it so deep?

Comment: @loganfsmyth please see my updated code snippet, I included a real-world use case very similar to mine

Comment: Having had that top-level "views" folder in an application before, I personally found it frustrating for exactly this reason. I opted to just move `editor_view` and other such to the top instead. It's already got `view` in the name. Sticking them all in a folder called `view` and in a page-specific folder doesn't offer any meaningful logic. If you need page-specific logic like "what is loaded on article_view", the import/export dependency graph will already tell you that.

Comment: I must say, I would not completely flatten your source hierarchy. I actually find it quite useful to have this kind of structuring in non-trivial projects. Just don't let it get too deep. So if `editor_view` could actually be useful to other views too, but incidentally is just needed by `article_page`, you should pull it up a level.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your project tooling and structure, you have some options.

**A)** You could publish part of your dependencies as stand-alone modules, perhaps in a private registry. You can then install them with npm and require them like any other external dependency.

**B)** Many module systems support some sort of path mapping. The [vue-js webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/fb39683846944f874244f88be4b05a1a2f1b7c96/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L27) uses [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)'s [alias feature](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to set `@` to the source code root. TypeScript supports [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) too. After you introduce that mapping you can use

```
import { numberUtil } from '@/utils/number_util';
```

This approach basically introduces a private namespace for your modules.
It is safe, in that you could only ever shadow an npm module with the name `@` which is an invalid name and therefore cannot exist.

For your example, you would have to have these entries in your `compilerOptions`:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "@/*": ["*"]
}
```

Or if you only want to import modules from `utils`, you could change the mapping to `"@/*": ["utils/*"]` and import using `'@/number_util'`.

**C)** Another thing to consider is to improve your project structure. Depending on your actual project, it might make sense to apply the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) at one point or another. Maybe [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) the dependency into `editor_text_area` instead of letting it import it itself.

Comment: Thank you! Unless I'm missing something obvious, the "alias" approach is a lot like the "non-relative" import I mentioned in my question. How is that different?

Comment: @benjaminz Depending on the actual resolution algorithm of the module system in use, the alias method might as well shadow an installed npm module. When you use `@` to refer to the repository root that should cause no trouble though. However, *my recommendation is to use __root-relative imports__*, as described in my update.

Comment: I tried the '/utils/number_util' approach but it doesn't work, it's complaining that module cannot be found, but when I remove the leading slash, it works just fine. What `compilerOptions` did you use that made it work? I checked the doc, and it seems the leading slash is only supported when you just do `import '/utils/number_util`

Comment: @benjaminz I just tried it myself, and `/` always resolves to the actual *file system root* regardless of any compiler configuration. Sorry, I should not have relied on second hand information from another SO post. In light of that new information I would suggest you go with option *B*. See my updated answer for further details.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `"baseUrl": "./src",` to you `tsconfig.json`,

then you can `import * as utils from 'utils'` to import `./src/utils/index.ts`