# Why this import line doesn't have an export

Tags: javascript, import, export

I just learned import/export for JS today but I saw this code from [here](https://gitlab.com/losnappas/web3-login) but it uses something like,

```
import { modal, configure } from 'web3-login';
```

But I thought it was supposed to be like,

```
import { modal, configure } from './web3-login.js';
```

What does `web3-login` mean? It is a shorthand?

And also, I can't an `export` anywhere in the code. I thought we should have like,

```
export function modal()
```

How come?

UPDATE: I originally found the file when I downloaded from - wordpress.org/plugins/ethpress but it doesn't use node. It's just a WordPress plugin. And there're no traces of `web3-login` text in a function or export.

Comment: `./abc` if a relative path and refers to a file in your project. `abc` is a module installed in your project; node will look for it in the node_modules folder. All of this is explained in detail here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers

Comment: @ChrisG I originally found the file when I downloaded from - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ethpress/ but it doesn't use node. It's just a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Doesn't make much of a difference, but here's MDN then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @ChrisG Meaning there's a function or package called `web3-login`? I searched the entire foldes/files and I can't find something named after that. I even searched for `type="module"` and got nothing. I don't know how I can show you the stuff in the plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative vs. non-relative module import for custom modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164231/relative-vs-non-relative-module-import-for-custom-modules)

Comment: You are linking to the package. In your question. https://gitlab.com/losnappas/web3-login#installation-as-component

Comment: @ChrisG No, it doesn't. I searched the links and I got this - https://nimb.ws/eR7SKg

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://gitlab.com/losnappas/web3-login/-/blob/master/dist/index.es.js#L1858

Comment: @ChrisG Under the plugin dist folder, there's no index.es.js. But there's `const id = 'web3-login-root';` under main.js. If that is the reference to import, then why is it `web3-login-root` and not `web3-login`?

Comment: As you can see from the surrounding code, that's the id of the root HTML element for the login component. I'm still not sure what your actual goal is here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm trying to learn import statement for JS

Comment: Ok then. I don't see why you would go to a random weird web3 module for that but maybe turn to the official docs first.

Answer (score 1):

-- when you are importing from node_modueles you use just package folder name like 'web3-login'

-- when you import some exported function from your project structure you use './web3-login.js'. this means you are importing some function that is exported from same directory that you are currently into.

Comment: It's from a WordPress plugin and it doesn't use node or npm. I searched the plugin folders/files and there's no package or function called 'web3-login'

Answer (score 0):

It uses `web3-login` instead of `./web3-login.js` because it's downloaded with npm (Node Package Manager). If you were trying to import a local file you have created yourself in your folder structure you would use: `./web3-login.js` but because it's now referring to a npm package you won't have to write more than just the package name.

Comment: I downloaded the file from - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ethpress/ and it's not using npm. It's just a WordPress plugin. So how it could work?